# Print both list returned by a single function

Tags: python, list, function, for-loop

I'm trying to print out both the list returned by a single function. I keep getting:

> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

```
def foods(x):
    fruits = []
    vegetables = []
    # code
    return fruits, vegetables

for food1, food2 in foods(x):
    print(food1+" "+food2)
```

If I use `in foods(x)[0]` or `in foods(x)[1]` I can print them out individually but I'm trying to print both at the same time.

Comment: The linked answer does not answer the question. The problem is not the print statement - you can print two lists like this: print([1,2,3]+[4,5])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If fruits and vegetables are the same size:

```
def foods(x):
    fruits = ["apple","banana","orange"]
    vegetables = ["tomato","mushrooms","beans"]
    return fruits, vegetables

my_fruits, my_vegetables = foods(x)
for food1, food2 in zip(my_fruits, my_vegetables):
    print(food1+" "+food2)
```

output

```
apple tomato
banana mushrooms
orange beans
```

otherwise:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
def foods(x):
    fruits = ["apple","banana","orange"]
    vegetables = ["tomato","mushrooms"]
    return fruits, vegetables

my_fruits, my_vegetables = foods(x)
for food1, food2 in zip_longest(my_fruits, my_vegetables):
    print(food1,food2)
```

output:

```
apple tomato
banana mushrooms
orange None
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use a comma:

```
print(food1, foo2)
```

[will automatically show the items separated with a space](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) (well really by whatever `sep` is set to, but that's a single space by default).

Python is not Java (or javascript, or PHP), it won't implicitly convert stuff to strings when you add a string to something else. If you want such a conversion (you usually don't), you have to do it manually.

Incidentally your snippet still won't work:

```py
for food1, food2 in foods(x):
```

means the result of `foods` is an iterable of iterables of length 2. But `foods` just returns a tuple, so should be

```py
food1, food2 = foods(x)
```

Alternatively, if `foods` *is supposed* to return pairs of a veggie and a fruit, you need to construct those pairs: `return a, b` will return one pair of two iterables, to return an iterable of pairs you need to [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) them together:

```py
return zip(fruits, vegetables)
```

in that case your iteration will work.